# PHP not working after changing apache DocumentRoot

Tags: php, apache

I have just setup the LAMP server on Debian. The initial tests were fine. After that, I've decided to change the home directory from "/var/www/" to something like "/home/user/public_html/". I did this changes in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default".

The problem I am facing now is, that the PHP does not work in the new home folder. PHP sites are now parsed as text files and I can see the full source in browser (when clicking on view page source).

What can I do, that the PHP will also work under that path (and not only under /var/www)?

Answer (score 0):

Look in php.ini in your php folder. There should be entries to change to 'doc_root' as well as 'extension_dir'. Make sure these are set, then restart Apache and it should work.

Comment: I have tired, but it's not working. The PHP is still working at /var/www, but not under /home/... The file I edited is /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Hmm. Could it be a typo....trailing /, should be `doc_root =/home/user/public_html` with no trailing '/'. Also, I have had issues with apache restarting. To be safe perhaps restart the machine? Perhaps permissions? Try another folder, eg /var/mytest